# Removing AFNetworking Authenticate Header

Tags: ios, authentication, httprequest, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2.x with AFHTTPSessionManager. The request I am sending doesn't require authentication. I am able to get the expected response with curl request on my terminal:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST https://myapp.com/api/events/box-office/baskets/get-or-create/

HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 17 Nov 2015 04:09:23 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
```

I am aware that we can remove the authenticate header by:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer clearAuthorizationHeader];
```

But it seems not working if I fire the same POST request with AFHTTPSessionManager as I will get this response:

```
2015-11-16 21:10:58.011 myapp[48771:16036168] [Error] POST 'https://myapp.com/api/events/box-office/baskets/get-or-create/' (401) [4.6264 s]: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fde11e90ed0> { URL: https://myapp.com/api/events/box-office/baskets/get-or-create/ } { status code: 401, headers {
Allow = "POST, OPTIONS";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Tue, 17 Nov 2015 04:10:54 GMT";
Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
Vary = Cookie;
"Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"api\"";
"X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
```

These lines catch my eyes:

```
Request failed: unauthorized (401)
"Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"api\"";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
```

As I am not getting these if I make the curl request shown above. Neither am I not supposed to send any authentication header to the server. 
If I add -u username:password (invalid credentials) into the curl request, I will get a similar error response:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -u devb01@gmail.com:testtest https://myapp.com/api/events/box-office/baskets/get-or-create/

HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 17 Nov 2015 03:10:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="api"
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
```

I wonder why AFHTTPSessionManager seemed to embed authenticate header into the POST request and I could not remove it. Any thoughts are appreciated.

BTW, I don't have control of the server code...